# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, key, private-key

I want to connect from my Mac (terminal) to GCP instance (centos) by running `ssh -i new_ssh_key centos@0.0.0.0`
and I got the error `centos@0.0.0.0: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`.

All works well till yesterday when SCP command did not worked out so I changed the permissions and probably something went wrong and now I can not connect to centos server at all.

Appreciated any help on this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed with adding below lines in /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

As shown：
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this same permission-denied issue, but in my own case, I was trying to connect to the EC2 instance using ssh from my MacBook Pro M2.

1. I have rightful permission to my `.pem` file
2. I was referencing the right path to the `.pem` file

But I wasn't specifying ec2-user, which I assumed should be default when I created my EC2 instance, but that wasn't the case. i.e

`ssh -i ./ec2-course.pem ec2-13-52-102-83.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

Steps that helped me to fix:

1. Give permission to your .pem file

   - `chmod 400 ec2-course.pem`
2. Add ec2-user@ to the Public IPv4 DNS `<ec2-user@ec2-13-52-102-83.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com>`. So the full command to ssh becomes

   - `ssh -i ./ec2-course.pem ec2-user@ec2-13-52-102-83.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`